# No data in application-insights when deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a .net core 2 MVC web application that uses application insights on Azure.
I also configured nlog to trace with application insights.
**Everything works on my pc, as I found exceptions and tracing on azure**, but when I deploy the application and use it on azure it doesn't generates any event on application insights (I found only the events in the log file).

So I tried to create an instance of TelemetryClient in a controller and it **works even in the the deployed instance**:

```
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient()
{
    InstrumentationKey = "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"
};
tc.Context.User.Id = Environment.MachineName;
tc.Context.Session.Id = "session_id";
tc.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
tc.TrackTrace("Privacy page says hello with TelemetryClient");
```

Here are the snippets of my project:

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"
  }
}
```

appsettings.Staging.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:dom.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dom;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I defined the same ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value on my VS and on Azure (Staging) to be sure to load the same appsettings and deployed all the files.

I load the configuration in this way

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()              
    .Build();
```

CreateWebHostBuilder is this

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfiguration config) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext) =>
        {
            //config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(
            logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
        .UseApplicationInsights() // Enable Application Insights
        .UseNLog();
```

nlog.config contains

```
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="aiTarget" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="f" />
  </rules>
```

It seems to me that something is wrong in the configuration or the InstrumentationKey, but I don't know how to inspect it.

Any idea, or... is there any way to know how the application insights library is configured in order to find some useful info to solve the problem? I tried with the remote debugging but I have no idea of what inspect.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you have set another application insights key in azure portal -> your web application -> configuration-> application settings.

Please check if you did this or not:

[image]

If the key is there, you need remove it. Or put this line of code `AddEnvironmentVariables()` before the `AddJsonFile()`, like below:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables() //put this before AddJsonFile()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)                 
    .Build();
```

Please let me know if you have more issues.

Comment: Yes @IvanYang, this was the problem. I deleted the key APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY and now it works! :-)